# Cognitive Service show Fill words and hide personal data

Tags: azure, nlp, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services, transcription

We use the Azure Batch Transcription Service to get the Transcript of an Audio / Speech.

In here we noticed, that sometimes filler words like "uhm", "hm" or something similar are included, but very rarely - also as we used this service for a few months already and we have the feeling as if it "got less" (so less "uhm"s in the transcript)

Q1: Is there a way to get the fill words? We want to recieve them within the transcript.

Also, as we sometimes record conversations it can happen that someone says a name or is talking about other personal information.

Q2: Is there a way to "filter" those personal information / words within the transcript?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't think there is a way to filter personal data/ word when translate. We only can do profanity Filter for batch transcription.

But I agree this feature will be very helpful. I will forward this feature request to product group to see if we can have this in the feature.

Thing I will suggest is to optimize the transcription as last to filter the sensitive information.

Regards,
Yutong